# compiler specific core dumps

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, redhat

I work for a telecom application product. I am facing an issue with my c++ code for last couple of days. I have been given a task to make the product to work on `HP server with RHEL` (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OS. And I am facing core dumps for each and every flow of the application. The stack gets corrupted for some unknown reason for each core dump. But the same code works fine on `Windriver 2.0 as well as 4.0`. However while doing some r&d I increased the stack size from `10MB to unlimited` and now I am not seeing core dumps anymore. But windriver works fine with even `8MB`. I think its some compiler specific issue. It will be of great help if someone puts some light on the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with some playground code as well? Real world applications are usually too complex to tell where the problem is. If you have source code, create a new copy of it and start deleting/commenting code. I think you quickly find parts of code that are responsible for that.

Comment: Definitely I will try that @izidor. But I suspect it to be compiler issue, not a code issue as the code is performing fine on live systems. As the compilers have different types of optimization schemes, may be this problem could be solved with some specific compilation option.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the compiler that you need to set stack size to unlimited on uses more stack space then Windriver. This is not a big surprise considering stack usage is highly dependent on how the compiler optimizes. Inlining functions would reduce stack usage for instance.